# How to identify body part names in a text with python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to specify whether an entity is a body part. For example in "Other specified disorders of the right ear," I want to be able to identify the right ear as an entity. I tried some named entity recognition methods but they identify all entities, not just the body parts. I tried using scispacy to do so but I have not managed so far. I tried concise_concepts from spacy to create a separate entity for body parts but that didn't work either. Please guide me through how I can do that and a snippet code would be appreciated.

Comment: See the guide to WordNet here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760674/ner-how-to-check-if-a-common-noun-indicates-a-place-subcategorization/72761290#72761290

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. Though it identifies foot as body_part but doesn't identify feet.

Comment: WordNet only contains lemmas (base forms of words, so not plurals). So you would need to use a lemmatizer and check the lemmas. Also note the lists of words in WordNet are not perfect and you should check them against your data and expect to make adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this code based on [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760674/ner-how-to-check-if-a-common-noun-indicates-a-place-subcategorization/72761290#72761290) almost detects everything correctly but it needs lemmatization.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import nltk 
nltk.download('wordnet')
part = wn.synsets('body_part')[0]

def is_body_part(candidate):
    for ss in wn.synsets(candidate):
        # only get those where the synset matches exactly
        name = ss.name().split(".", 1)[0]
        if name != candidate:
            continue
        hit = part.lowest_common_hypernyms(ss)
        if hit and hit[0] == part:
            return True
    return False

# true things
for word in ("finger", "hand", "head", "feet", 'foot', 'hair'):
    print(is_body_part(word), word, sep="\t")

# false things
for word in ("cat", "dog", "fish", "cabbage", "knife"):
    print(is_body_part(word), word, sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
True    finger
True    hand
True    head
False   feet # have to lemmatize it to foot
True    foot
True    hair
False   cat
False   dog
False   fish
False   cabbage
False   knife
```